# Set value in async foreach always returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to store order id to next orders as parent id but parent id always show null.

```
let parentId = null;

await Promise.all(ordersProducts.map(async (orderProducts) => {
  orderProducts.parent_id = parentId;

  console.log(parentId) // Here parentId is always null

  let order = await order.create(orderProducts);

    if (! parent_id) {
        parentId = order.id;
    }
}));
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code at your end and checked if `parentId = order.id;` is setting value or not and what happens in next loop inside `map()`?

Comment: After setting parent id, I console it and showing correct value but before the next iteration, it shows null

Comment: `parentId` will always be `null`. You're assigning `orderProducts.parent_id` to `null`. So what's the issue here? Are you not expecting null?

Comment: I tried it with forEach also but not working

Comment: `foo = bar` copies the value of `bar` into `foo`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is assigning `orderProducts.parent_id` to `null`.

Your first line is:

```
let parentId = null;
```

Then you're essentially saying:

```
orderProducts.parent_id = null
```

It will always give you `null`.

I guess what you're after is:

```
parentId = orderProducts.parent_id;
```

Additionally, your `if` statement does not contain valid logic:

```
if (! parent_id) {
    parentId = order.id;
}
```

`parent_id` does not exist.

You may need to change it to:

```
if (!orderProducts.parent_id)
```

Comment: After first loop, I am setting parentId = order.id;

Answer (score 0):

This issue is mainly happening due to the async behaviour of `map()` method which is demonstrated below:

```js
(async function() {
  let parentId = null;
  let ordersProducts = [{id: 1, parent_id: null}, {id: 2, parent_id: null}]
  await Promise.all(ordersProducts.map(async(p, i) => {
    p.parent_id = parentId;

    console.log(`Before await: loop #${i+1}`)
    let order = await Promise.resolve({id: i+2});
    console.log(`After await: loop #${i+1}`)

    if (!parentId) {
      parentId = order.id;
    }
  }));
}());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You can clearly see in the console the execution order:

```
Before await: loop #1
Before await: loop #2
After await: loop #1
After await: loop #2
```

As you can see, both the `Before await` inside `map()` are logged first and then both of the `After await` are logged. Due to this behaviour `parentId` is always null as it is updated later on after all console logs `console.log(parentId)` are displayed.

You can try to update your code this way:

```
let parentId = null;
const promises = ordersProducts.map((p, i) => order.create(p));
const orders = await Promise.all(promises);
ordersProducts = ordersProducts.map((p, i) => {
    p.parent_id = parentId;
    console.log(parentId)
    parentId = !parentId ? orders[i].id : parentId;   
    return p
});

//console.log(ordersProducts)
```

DEMO:

```js
(async function() {
  let parentId = null;
  let ordersProducts = [{id: 1, parent_id: null}, {id: 2, parent_id: null}]
  const promises = ordersProducts.map((p, i) => Promise.resolve({id: i+2}));
  const orders = await Promise.all(promises);
  ordersProducts = ordersProducts.map((p, i) => {
    p.parent_id = parentId;
    console.log(parentId)
    parentId = !parentId ? orders[i].id : parentId;   
    return p
  });
  
  //console.log(ordersProducts)
}());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```